# Read a text file in VB

Tags: vb.net

New Visual basic programmer here. Trying to get a textfile to be read by the program but it seems to simply not work, no error messages or anything. It just does not grab the values at all

The textfile name is exactly the same.

```
Public Sub ReadDef()

    Dim DefSR As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("BikeDefault.txt")

    GlobalTotBikes = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalRentRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalHSTRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalTourRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalGPSRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalInsurRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalWaterBotRate = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalNextBookNum = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalNextCustNum = DefSR.ReadLine()
    GlobalNextInvoiceNum = DefSR.ReadLine()

    DefSR.Close()

End Sub
```

I've compared this code a bunch of times to the example I was given and I see nothing different.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?  I'd make sure that you use the fully qualified path, and not just the relative path.  Also, are you sure the file actually has lines of data in it?

Comment: Im absolutely certain. The file is located in the projects bin/debug folder which im told means I can simply have the code as it is above and it will pick it up.

Comment: Try fully qualifying the filename with the path.  Otherwise it'll read from the "Current Directory", and it's not always obvious what that is.  It might even be creating a totally new (and empty) file.

Comment: Hmm it seems this was the problem. Turns out I've been lied too or the information is outdated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple search on google http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader-vbnet

Make 100% sure `BikeDefault.txt` exists. If you wish to make sure, copy the file over to the `C:\` Drive to keep it simple and replace your `BikeDefault.txt` with `"C:\\BikeDefault.txt"`

**You can use the StreamReader like so:**

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
    ' Store the line in this String.
    Dim line As String
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\\BikeDefault.txt"
    ' Create new StreamReader instance with Using block.
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FilePath)
        ' Read one line from file
        line = reader.ReadLine
    End Using

    ' Write the line we read from "file.txt"
    Console.WriteLine(line)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Or keep it simple with `File.ReadAllLines`.

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("MyTextFile.txt")
    'Code here to read each line
Next line
```

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
IO.File.ReadAllText("BikeDefault.txt")
```